# Homepage product display issue

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

In homepage  products are not displaying , that how many i mentioned in single line .

If i mentioned 5 products in each line , it shows 4 products and the next line remaining one will be displayed . Then second line also in the same way and complete homepage having the issue . You will get understand when you see the bellow image .

[image]

you can check in this [page link](http://52.26.22.150)

i am working on magento1.9 . Please help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below Remove the clear :left see the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your stylesheet styles.css on line 4438 to:

```
.products-grid--max-5-col > li {
    width: 14.22222%;
    margin-right: 2.22222%;
}
```

Comment: Could you accept my answer please? In desperate need of more points!

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/design/frontend/Your-Theme/Your-Package/layout/catalog.xml

There is

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

between the tag `<catalog_category_default></catalog_category_default>`

change it to `<action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action>`

same change between `<catalog_category_layered></catalog_category_layered>`

This layout for category page with layered navigation